# Ejecutar una clase de otro fichero .py

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

como se puede ejecutar una función  llamada 'fun_1', de la clase 'Aplicacion', Del archivo P1.py desde otro archivo p2.py??

Cada vez que lo intento me ejecuta todos los métodos definidos en ese archivo p1.py

Solo quiero ejecutar la función con todo lo que tenga la función.

Me pueden ayudar ..

Este es el codigo lo mas resumido posible:

Esta es la aplicacion principal, con una pestaña, unos botones que abren mas pestañas, la idea es añadir X pestañas posibles, el problea esta cuando intenta añadir pestañas desdeun boton en parte superior que dice ABRIR.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ScrollableNotebook import *


class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Example")
        self.notebook = ScrollableNotebook(
            self.root, wheelscroll=True, tabmenu=True)
        frame1 = Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(frame1, text="WorkSpace")
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        text = Text(frame1)
        text.pack()
        Label(frame1, text="Pantalla PRINCIPAL").pack()
        Button(frame1,
               text="Issues EXTRACIONES",
               command=self.abrir_ISSETX,
               ).pack()
        Button(frame1,
               text="Issues DESVIACIONES",
               command=self.abrir_ISSDES,
               ).pack()

    def abrir_ISSETX(self):
        self.cuaderno = Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.cuaderno, text="Issues EXTRACIONES")

    def abrir_ISSDES(self):
        self.cuaderno = Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.cuaderno, text="Issues DESVIACIONES")

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplicacion()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: Panatlla principal]

Ahora el segundo fichero que es un codigo de una persona que publico, como añadir la X en las pestañas, desde este archivo que lo he configurado a mi gusto, sin tocar la licencia, he añadido una funcion que me llama a la funcion del archivo principal:

He probado varias formas de abrir una nueva pestaña y os paso esta por escribir algo.

```
def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
        from Example import Aplicacion
        Aplicacion.abrir_ISSETX(Aplicacion)
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) Muhammet Emin TURGUT 2020
# For license see LICENSE
from posixpath import commonpath
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import font
import os
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
release = True
path = os.path.expanduser("~/")
path_icon = path+"Compliance/image/"
count = 0
class ScrollableNotebook(ttk.Frame):
    _initialized = False
    def __init__(self,parent,wheelscroll=False,tabmenu=False,*args,**kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialize()
            self._inititialized = True
        kwargs["style"] = "ScrollableNotebook"
        self._active = None
        self.xLocation = 0
        self.WorkSpac_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path_icon+r"workspace.png").resize((20, 20)))
        #self.novo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path_icon+r"novo.png").resize((25, 25)))
        self.notebookContent = ttk.Notebook(self,**kwargs)
        self.notebookContent.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.notebookTab = ttk.Notebook(self,**kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",lambda e:self._tabChanger(e))
        if wheelscroll==True: 
            self.notebookTab.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._wheelscroll)
            self.notebookTab.bind("<Button-4>", self._wheelscroll)
            self.notebookTab.bind("<Button-5>", self._wheelscroll)
        slideFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        slideFrame.place(relx=1.0, x=0, y=1, anchor=NE)
        self.menuSpace=30
        if tabmenu==True:
            self.menuSpace=50
            self.bottomTab = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text="  \u2630  ", 
                                background='#DF2E2E',
                                foreground='#F6D167',
                                width=5, 
                                anchor="center"
                                )
            self.bottomTab.bind("<1>",self._bottomMenu)
            self.bottomTab.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=14)
        self.bottomTab_novo = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                #image=self.novo,
                                text="Abrir",
                                width=5,
                                background="#082032",
                                foreground="white",
                                )
        self.bottomTab_novo.bind("<1>",self._bottomMenu_novo)
        self.bottomTab_novo.pack(side=LEFT, ipady=14)

        self.leftArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text=" \u276E ",
                                foreground="#297F87",
                                )
        self.leftArrow.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start())
        self.leftArrow.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._release_callback)
        self.leftArrow.pack(side=LEFT, ipady=14)
        self.rightArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text=" \u276F ",
                                foreground="#297F87",
                                )
        #rightArrow.bind("<1>",self._rightSlide)
        self.rightArrow.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start())
        self.rightArrow.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._release_callback)
        self.rightArrow.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=10)

        self.notebookContent.bind("<Configure>", self._resetSlide)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)
        self.notebookContent.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.notebookContent.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)
    
    def _release_callback(self, e):
        global release
        release = True
        self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
    
    def on_tab_close_press(self, event):
        name = self.identify(event.x, event.y)  
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index
    
    def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return None
        name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if index != 0:
                if self._active == index:
                    self.forget(index)
                    self.notebookContent.forget(index)
                    self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")
        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None
    
    def _initialize(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.images = (
        tk.PhotoImage("img1", data='''
            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
        ''' ),
            tk.PhotoImage("img3", data="""
            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
        """)
        )
        self.style.element_create("tab_btn_close", "image", "img1",
                            #("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img2"), 
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img3"), border=15, sticky=''
        )
        self.style.layout("ScrollableNotebook", [("ScrollableNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        self.style.layout("ScrollableNotebook.Tab", [
            ("ScrollableNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe", 
                "children": [
                    ("ScrollableNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top", 
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("ScrollableNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top", 
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("ScrollableNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": 'nsew'}),
                                    ("ScrollableNotebook.tab_btn_close", {"side": "left", "sticky": 'nsew'}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])
        self.style.configure('ScrollableNotebook',
                            background='#082032',
        )
        self.style.configure("ScrollableNotebook.Tab",
            background='#FDD2BF',
            foreground='#012443',
            padding=[2, 2],
            anchor="center",
            justify="center",
            font=('Sans-Serif', 12, font.BOLD)
        )         
        self.style.map('ScrollableNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "#B61919"),
                                                    ("active", "#FF6B6B")],
                                        foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                    ("active", "#012443")]
                                                    )
    
    def _wheelscroll(self, event):
        # if event.delta > 0:
        #     Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
        # else:
        #     Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        global count
        # # respond to Linux or Windows wheel event
        # if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
        #     count -= 1
        #     Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
        #     #self._rightSlide()
        # if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
        #     count += 1
        #     Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        #     #self._leftSlide()
        print(count)

    def _bottomMenu(self,event):
        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=13)
        tabListMenu = Menu(self, tearoff = 0)
        for tab in self.notebookTab.tabs():
            tabListMenu.add_command(label=self.notebookTab.tab(tab, option="text"),
                                    command= lambda temp=tab: self.select(temp),
                                    background='#ccffff', 
                                    foreground='blue',
                                    font=self.text_font,
                                    activebackground='#004c99',
                                    activeforeground='white')
        tabListMenu.entryconfig('WorkSpace  ', 
                                accelerator="ALT+W",
                                image=self.WorkSpac_icon, 
                                compound='left', 
                                label='  WorkSpace')
        try: 
            tabListMenu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        except:
            self.bottomTab.configure(background='#DF2E2E',
                                foreground='#F6D167')

    def _bottomMenu_novo(self,event):
        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=13)
        self.tabListMenu = Menu(self, tearoff = 0)
        #for tab in self.notebookTab.tabs():
        self.tabListMenu.add_command(
            label="  Extraciones", 
            #accelerator='Ctrl+F',
            command=self._abrir_issuesEXT,
            background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
            activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
            font=self.text_font,
        )
        self.tabListMenu.add_command(
            label="  Desviaciones", 
            #accelerator='Ctrl+F',
            command=self._abrir_issuesEXT,
            background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
            activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
            font=self.text_font,
        )
        self.tabListMenu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    
    def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
        from Example import Aplicacion
        Aplicacion.abrir_ISSETX(Aplicacion)

    def _tabChanger(self,event):
        if event.state == 0:
            self._resetSlide(event=None)
        try:
            self.notebookContent.select(self.notebookTab.index("current"))
        except: pass

    def _rightSlide(self):
        global release
        release = False
        self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#DF2E2E')
        while not release:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if self.notebookTab.winfo_width()>self.notebookContent.winfo_width()-self.menuSpace:
                if (self.notebookContent.winfo_width()-(self.notebookTab.winfo_width()+self.notebookTab.winfo_x()))<=self.menuSpace+5:
                    self.xLocation-=20
                    self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation,y=0)
                else:
                    self._release_callback(e=None)
    
    def _leftSlide(self):
        global release
        release = False
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#DF2E2E')
        while not release:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if not self.notebookTab.winfo_x()== 0:
                self.xLocation+=20
                self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation,y=0)
            else:
                    self._release_callback(e=None)

    def _resetSlide(self, event):
        self.notebookTab.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.xLocation = 0

    def add(self,frame,**kwargs):
        named = kwargs['text']
        if len(self.notebookTab.winfo_children())!=0:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text=named,state="hidden")
        else:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text=named,state="hidden")
        self.notebookTab.add(ttk.Frame(self.notebookTab),**kwargs)
        id_tab = self.tabs()[-1]
        self.notebookTab.select(id_tab)

    def forget(self,tab_id):
        #self.notebookContent.forget(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id))
        self.notebookTab.forget(tab_id)

    def hide(self,tab_id):
        #self.notebookContent.hide(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id))
        self.notebookTab.hide(tab_id)

    def identify(self,x, y):
        return self.notebookTab.identify(x,y)

    def index(self,tab_id):
        return self.notebookTab.index(tab_id)
        #return self.notebookTab.index(self.notebookTab.select('current'))

    def __ContentTabID(self,tab_id):
        return self.notebookContent.tabs()[self.notebookTab.tabs().index(tab_id)]

    def insert(self,pos,frame, **kwargs):
        #self.notebookContent.insert(pos,frame, **kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.insert(pos,frame,**kwargs)

    def select(self,tab_id):
        self.notebookTab.select(tab_id)
        if tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame':
            self._resetSlide(event=None)
            self._release_callback(e=None)
        elif tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame2' or tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame3' or tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame4':
            Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
            self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
        else:
            Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
            self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')

    def tab(self,tab_id, option=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs_Content = kwargs.copy()
        kwargs_Content["text"] = "" # important
        #self.notebookContent.tab(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id), option=None, **kwargs_Content)
        return self.notebookTab.tab(tab_id, option=None, **kwargs)

    def tabs(self):
        #return self.notebookContent.tabs()
        return self.notebookTab.tabs()

    def enable_traversal(self):
        self.notebookContent.enable_traversal()
        self.notebookTab.enable_traversal()
```

Hay muchos comentarios porque voy haciendo pruebas, sorry.

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: el codigo es lo mas importante...

Comment: te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Que he intentado .. pues la aplicación la tengo en marcha, y trabajo con diferentes clases en diferentes archivos .py, el código es enorme lo tengo en github, y no sé si merece la pena pegarlo todo, sólo intento comprender cómo puedo solo usar la función de una clase .. porque cuando lo hago me ejecuta todas las funciones, es en tkinter, me crear la propia ventana de nuevo y no quiero eso ..

Comment: asumo que al decir  ***no sé si merece la pena pegarlo todo*** es por que no has leido los link que te envie ...

Comment: Lo he leído en otras ocacion

Comment: deberías tomar la parte del código que no te funciona y tratar de hacer un ejemplo mínimo reproducible; para que nosotros a partir de ese codigo podamos decir... mira aqui esta el error ... cambia esto por esto o agrega esto ... o asi no se hace ... pero si no nos das algo que se supone que debemos hacer adivinar el error??? hacerte todo el script???

Comment: Es que no sale error .. es igual gracias

Comment: Como dice el compañero, deberias poner un mínimo de código para poder ayudarte. Quizas el problema es que al importar P1.py desde P2.py tienes código fuera de la función, el cual deberia ir dentro de un `if __name__ == "__main__": `

Comment: Si estoy en ello, creando un pequeño ejemplo adaptado al error .. cuando esté os paso ..

Comment: hecho he resumido el codigo de la ventana principal, lo mas clara posiblem agradezco la ayuda

Comment: @LOPUMAJoseAlvaroCedeño los comentarios que agregues al código y al mismo POST son muy bien recibidos nos ayudan a entender que estas haciendo en el código cuando no es un código descriptivo; incluso hacer esto en el trabajo o cualquier desarrollo que hagas es una muy buena practica. y si tienes mala memoria como yo te ayudara en un futuro ...

Comment: Ok entiendo lo tendre en cuenta.. no soy mucho de comentarios pero lo tendre en cuenta, si hay problema con el codigo decirme, y comento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el código que has puesto, te puedo decir que me resulta extraña esta función:

```
def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
    from Example import Aplicacion
    Aplicacion.abrir_ISSETX(Aplicacion)
```

No debería funcionar, incluso deberia dar un error al hacer la llamada, porque `Aplicación` es una clase y `abrir_ISSETX` no es un método estático. Deberia ser algo como esto:

```
def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
    from Example import Aplicacion
    aplicacion = Aplicacion()
    aplicacion.abrir_ISSETX()
```

Pero no creo que te sirva. Quizas lo que necesites es pasarle al constructor la instancia, es decir:

```
     self.notebook = ScrollableNotebook(self.root, wheelscroll=True, 
                     tabmenu=True, application=self)
```

Y entonces:

```
class ScrollableNotebook(ttk.Frame):
    _initialized = False
    def __init__(self,parent,wheelscroll=False,tabmenu=False, application=None,*args,**kwargs):
       ...
       self._application = application
```

Por último:

```
 def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
        self._application.abrir_ISSETX()
```

Comment: Hola David, Gracias por tu respuesta pero he intentado hacerlo como dices, y me da un error. Al añadir self al constructor, me da un error : "
 "message": "Positional argument cannot appear after keyword arguments","                                       Lo he puesto como momentabas:                                                          
        self.notebook = ScrollableNotebook(
            self.root, 
            wheelscroll=True, 
            tabmenu=True,
            self,
        )

Comment: He modificado el código. Tienes que hacer esto: `self.notebook = ScrollableNotebook(self.root, wheelscroll=True, tabmenu=True, application=self)`

Comment: Pues funciona perfectamente.. MUCHAS GRACIAS. y para cerrar la pestaña desde un boton independiente, como seria?..

Comment: Yo tengo experiencia con QT. De TKinter poco. Te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta, a ver si alguien sabe cómo.

Comment: Gracias, aunque digas que tkinter poco, me has ayudado mucho.